# Writing conditions for users to add badges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `merit` gem and here is my condition to add badges to my users based on winrate

```
module Badges
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_update :badges_win_rate, if: :wr_60
  end

  def badges_win_rate
    wr = player.win_rate
    case
    when wr.between?(0.6, 0.7)
      player.add_badge(11) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 11}
    when wr.between?(0.7, 0.75)
      player.add_badge(12) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 12}
    when wr.between?(0.75, 0.8)
      player.add_badge(13) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 13}
    when wr.between?(0.8, 0.85)
      player.add_badge(14) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 14}
    when wr.between?(0.85, 0.9)
      player.add_badge(15) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 15}
    when wr > 0.9
      player.add_badge(16) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 16}
    end
  end

  private

  def wr_60
    player.win_rate > 0.59 && player.games.count > 20
  end
end
```

I have another method call `rm_badge` which will remove the badges of player based on badges id. For example, how can I use this method to remove badges of player when player's win rate drop from > 0.9 to > 0.85? Thanks

Comment: With your current logic isn't a player with a 0.90+ win rate just going to get an "11" badge?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the code.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that they can only have 1 badge? e.g. if their win rate is 0.82 they will have a badge 14 but not any of the others

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments one way to do this would just be to use the method `rm_badge` like so:

```
module Badges
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_update :badges_win_rate, if: :wr_60
  end

  def badges_win_rate
    wr = player.win_rate

    remove_all_badges

    case
    when wr.between?(0.6, 0.7)
      player.add_badge(11) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 11}
    when wr.between?(0.7, 0.75)
      player.add_badge(12) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 12}
    when wr.between?(0.75, 0.8)
      player.add_badge(13) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 13}
    when wr.between?(0.8, 0.85)
      player.add_badge(14) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 14}
    when wr.between?(0.85, 0.9)
      player.add_badge(15) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 15}
    when wr > 0.9
      player.add_badge(16) unless player.badges.any? {|b| b.id == 16}
    end
  end

  private

  def wr_60
    player.win_rate > 0.59 && player.games.count > 20
  end

  def remove_all_badges
    if player.badges
      player.badges.each do |badge|
        player.rm_badge badge.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```